# How to describe someone who talks too much

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

I want to find suitable words to describe a person who always jumps in the middle of a conversation and starts talking without considering or waiting for other people to finish their sentences.

Any suggestion?

Comment: _Buttinsky_ is the classic term in USAian.

Comment: *Kibitzer* is another possibility.

Comment: @BobRodes Hmmm, in Yiddish not really. It's a person who offers unwelcome and unsolicited advice. Tells you _Qd8-g5_ while you're considering a move.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Yes, true, and it's very common in the chess world as you say, probably because a lot of the best chess players in the US are New Yorkers and a lot of those are Jewish as well. But the sense of butting in is there as well. I'd say that neither of the terms have the sense of someone in a conversation who won't let his interlocutor finish what he's saying. They both imply third-party interference, don't they? I usually just call someone who does this an "interrupter." I don't think there's a nice, colorful word that exactly characterizes this particular sort of offender.

Comment: p.s. I'd love to find one though.

Comment: @BobRodes I don't think of interrupting when I think of a kibbitzer—rather someone who believess that he knows more than I do and (an important distinction) thinks he's helping.

Comment: Or any verb for the act?

Comment: @BobRodes There's something to said for umbrella terms like _big mouth._

Comment: @P.E.Dant I see. Well, I guess we disagree. Buttinskys think they are helping as well IMO, in much the same way that kibitzers do. Egos always have the idea that they need to give the benefit of their superior knowledge to the world, and that the world benefits from their doing so.  And I've found that kibitzers usually don't know as much as they think they do.

Comment: Well, I'd say _butt in_ is a good phrasal verb. It's not as much a pejorative as you're looking for, though. Maybe _horn in_ works.

Comment: @TDNguyen Sorry, we've gotten a bit off track. The usual verb for the act is *interrupt*. Interrupting a person when they are talking is generally considered rude, although some people talk so much that the only way to get a word in is to interrupt them. We have lots of words for people like that; a good slang term is *motor-mouth.*

Comment: @BobRodes A **motor-mouth** is simply a person who speaks without stopping. He may or may not necessarily interrupt people.

Comment: @SovereignSun That's right. If you will reread my comment, you will see that my point is that the only way to stop a motor-mouth from talking is to interrupt *him*, not that he interrupts people. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any good words or idioms that include both someone who talks too much *and* someone who interrupts others, but if you are just talking about someone who talks too much, you could call them:

> - A **[loudmouth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loudmouth)**
>     a person who talks a lot, especially in an offensive or stupid way
> - A **[gasbag](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gasbag?a=british)**
>     a person who always talks too much
> - A **[blowhard](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blowhard)**
>     an exceptionally boastful and talkative person.

Or describe them as:

> - **[Liking the sound of their own voice](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+the+sound+of+own+voice)** / **Loving the sound of their own voice**
>     To enjoy hearing oneself talk because one is pompous and/or self-centered.

If you are not worried about encompassing someone who talks too much, but are more interested in saying that they interrupt a lot, you could call them:

> - An **[interrupter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interrupter)**
>     one that interrupts

Although, this is not in common usage, and it can be used for *"a device for interrupting an electric current usually automatically"* (not that anyone would confuse it for that use in context).

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for verbs, then there are:

> - [interrupt](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interrupt)
>     to stop someone from speaking by saying or doing something, or to cause an activity or event to stop briefly:
>     [ I ] Please don’t interrupt until I’m finished.
>     [ T ] The picnic was interrupted by a rain shower.
>
> (Cambridge Dictionary)

The following are a number of related, casual verbs:

> - [butt in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/butt-in)
>     to interrupt a conversation or discussion or someone who is talking:
>     He kept on butting in with silly comments.
> - [chime in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/chime-in)
>     to speak in a conversation, esp. by interrupting:
>     Everyone at the table began to chime in with their opinions.
> - [chip in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chip-in?a=british)
>     mainly UK informal
>     to interrupt a conversation in order to say something:
>     I'll start and you can all chip in with your comments.
> - [cut in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cut-in)
>     to interrupt what someone is saying by saying something yourself:
>     I was just talking to Jan, when Dave cut in (on us/our conversation).
> - [horn in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/horn-in?a=british)
>     US informal
>     to try to become involved in a discussion or activity when you are not wanted:
>     She's always horning in on our conversations.
>
> (Cambridge Dictionary)